# get stable encryption/cipher text from RSA encryption in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, go, encryption

I am working on generating a stable cipher text every-time i am encrypting a value.
for example lets say i am encrypting "sai" then it because a $encrypted-string.
I was able to control the randomization in go and was able to generate a stable cipher text, i am not able to do it in typescript

```
randomFunc := func(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    // If seed is provided, use it for secure random number generation
    if seed != "" {
        h := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(seed))
        if _, err := h.Write(b); err != nil {
            return 0, err
        }
        copy(b, h.Sum(nil))
        return len(b), nil
    }
    // If seed is not provided, generate a random seed using crypto/rand
    return rand.Read(b)
}

ciphertext, err := rsa.EncryptOAEP(
    sha256.New(),
    SecureRandomReader{randomFunc},
    publicKey,
    plaintext,
    labelBytes,
)
```

if my plain text is "sai" and label bytes is "label" and seed is "seed" it always gives me the same cipher text

however typescript does not allow me to control the randomisation
here is the typescript equivalent

```
const sha256 = forge.md.sha256.create()
sha256.update(seed)
if (seed) {
      const ciphertextBuffer = publicKey.encrypt(forge.util.encodeUtf8(toBeEncrypted), 'RSA-OAEP', {
        md: sha256,
        mgf1: {
          md: sha256,
        },
        label: labelBytes,
      })
      ciphertextBase64 = forge.util.encode64(ciphertextBuffer)
```

but the cipher text here is continuously changing.
Before we get into the discussion on why randomness is more secure, i am okay with it not being secure, i just want to know how i can control randomization in typescript encryption/ is it even possible?

Comment: So you want to deliberately weaken an encryption system by compromising the RNG that powers it? This smells mighty bad. Why would you want to do that? (by explaining your *actual* use-case, you might discover a different approach that isn't so "unconventional")

Comment: not really, i want to do it so that i can get a stable identifier and associate to a userId 
a different identifier means i cant associate it with a single user event

Comment: then you should be using an encoding/hashing algorithm instead of encryption

Comment: i want this to be 2 way

Comment: Yes really, that does deliberately weaken or break the encryption.

Answer (score 1):

As with the *rsa* package in the Go code, *node-forge* also allows the seed to be provided by specifying the parameter of the same name in the options of the [`encrypt()`](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/main/lib/rsa.js#L1074) function (which calls for OAEP [`encode_rsa_oaep()`](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/main/lib/pkcs1.js#L63) where the parameters are applied). Likewise, label and OAEP- as well as MGF1-digest can be specified, e.g.:

```js
var pki = forge.pki
var rsa = forge.pki.rsa

var publicKeyPem = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAoZ67dtUTLxoXnNEzRBFB
mwukEJGC+y69cGgpNbtElQj3m4Aft/7cu9qYbTNguTSnCDt7uovZNb21u1vpZwKH
yVgFEGO4SA8RNnjhJt2D7z8RDMWX3saody7jo9TKlrPABLZGo2o8vadW8Dly/v+I
d0YDheCkVCoCEeUjQ8koXZhTwhYkGPu+vkdiqX5cUaiVTu1uzt591aO5Vw/hV4DI
hFKnOTnYXnpXiwRwtPyYoGTa64yWfi2t0bv99qz0BgDjQjD0civCe8LRXGGhyB1U
1aHjDDGEnulTYJyEqCzNGwBpzEHUjqIOXElFjt55AFGpCHAuyuoXoP3gQvoSj6RC
sQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`

var publicKey = pki.publicKeyFromPem(publicKeyPem)

var hmac = forge.hmac.create()
hmac.start('sha256', 'seed')                              // apply 'seed' as HMAC key...
hmac.update('\0'.repeat(32))                              // ...and 32 0x00 values as message
var seed = hmac.digest()

var encrypted = publicKey.encrypt('sai', 'RSA-OAEP', {    // apply 'sai' as plaintext
  md: forge.md.sha256.create(),                           // apply SHA-256 as OAEP digest
  mgf1: {
    md: forge.md.sha256.create()                          // apply SHA-256 as MGF1 digest
  },
  label: 'label',                                         // apply 'label' as label
  seed: seed.data
})

console.log(forge.util.bytesToHex(encrypted)) // 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
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/node-forge@0.7.0/dist/forge.min.js"></script>
```

This generates the same ciphertext as the following Go code (assuming the same key, plaintext, digests, label, and seed):

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/hex"
    "encoding/pem"
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

var seed = "seed"
var Reader io.Reader

type rngReader struct{}

func init() { Reader = &rngReader{} }
func (r *rngReader) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    //fmt.Println("key:", hex.EncodeToString(b))
    if seed != "" {
        h := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(seed))
        if _, err := h.Write(b); err != nil {
            return 0, err
        }
        copy(b, h.Sum(nil))
        return len(b), nil
    }
    // If seed is not provided, generate a random seed using crypto/rand
    return rand.Read(b)
}

func main() {

    var publicKeyData = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAoZ67dtUTLxoXnNEzRBFB
mwukEJGC+y69cGgpNbtElQj3m4Aft/7cu9qYbTNguTSnCDt7uovZNb21u1vpZwKH
yVgFEGO4SA8RNnjhJt2D7z8RDMWX3saody7jo9TKlrPABLZGo2o8vadW8Dly/v+I
d0YDheCkVCoCEeUjQ8koXZhTwhYkGPu+vkdiqX5cUaiVTu1uzt591aO5Vw/hV4DI
hFKnOTnYXnpXiwRwtPyYoGTa64yWfi2t0bv99qz0BgDjQjD0civCe8LRXGGhyB1U
1aHjDDGEnulTYJyEqCzNGwBpzEHUjqIOXElFjt55AFGpCHAuyuoXoP3gQvoSj6RC
sQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`

    plaintext := []byte("sai")
    labelBytes := []byte("label")

    pubKeyBlock, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(publicKeyData))
    var rsaPublicKey *rsa.PublicKey
    pubInterface, _ := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(pubKeyBlock.Bytes)
    rsaPublicKey = pubInterface.(*rsa.PublicKey)

    ciphertext, _ := rsa.EncryptOAEP(
        sha256.New(),
        Reader,
        rsaPublicKey,
        plaintext,
        labelBytes,
    )

    fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(ciphertext)) // 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
}
```

---

Even though you say that security is not your main concern, it should be reiterated for future readers that OAEP mandates a *random* seed for security reasons (see RFC 8017, 7.1.1. Encryption Operation, [step 2d](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#page-23)).
Also, by convention, OAEP commonly uses an empty label, and deviating from this may cause compatibility issues.